# Java Exception Handlng

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throw

I am trying to get a better understanding on exception handling. I have read my book and googled it but this block of code doesn't make sense to me. The way I have it understood before coming to this block of code is if a user enters an invalid number or a 0, then the `throw new ArithmeticException` throws the exception to the catch block, and the catch block takes care of it, then execution continues as normal. When I run this code, the code in the `catch block` gets executed but not the `throw new ArithmeticException` code. So my two questions are, why doesn't the `throw new ArithmeticException` code get executed as well, and why are there two different error messages being displayed for the same problem...?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App2 {

    public static int quotient(int number1, int number2)
    {
        if (number2 == 0)
        {
            throw new ArithmeticException("divisor cannot be zero");
        }

        return number1 / number2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter two integers");

        int number1 = input.nextInt();
        int number2 = input.nextInt();

        try
        {
            int result = quotient(number1, number2);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
        catch (ArithmeticException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("exception: integer can't be divided by 0");
        }

        System.out.println("execution continues");
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the "throw new .." code is not executing? And what are the two different errors that you get?

Comment: The `throw new ArithmeticException` line is executed. If it wasn't you wouldn't end up in the catch block and you wouldn't see the `"exception: integer can't be divided by 0"` message.

Comment: @eugenioy - Because in my stack trace it says
'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: divisor cannot be zero' 
I am not getting two errors, just that one. And I meant to say that in the code block has one error message stating "divisor cannot be zero" and in the other it says 'exception: integer can't be divided by zero'

Comment: What you have described is impossible. If the throw didn't execute, neither did the catch.

Comment: @EJP - Well if I enter 2 and then 0, in my console I see:
enter two integers
2
0
exception: integer can't be divider by zero
execution continues
NOT:
"divisor cannot be zero" followed by "exception: integer can't be divided by 0"

Comment: Exactly, so your catch block *wasn't* executed. Otherwise you would have seen the message it prints. Are you sure you're running the code you think you're running?

Comment: And can you please make up your mind about whether you see one message or two?

Comment: @EJP Well that is why I am confused. That is my question. What it's not being executed? That's the whole point why I am confused. So, in what scenario, would it be executed?

Comment: I am unable to make head or tail of your self-contradictions. If you saw the exception printed by your catch block, a throw was executed. If you didn't, it wasn't. I strongly suspect you're running different code from this. Recompile and retest.

Comment: What is your problem? I just executed your code and it does what you tell it to do.

Comment: @EJP I am seeing ONE message in my CONSOLE: "exception: integer can't be divider by 0"
But, in the book, in the code, why are two TWO different messages? In what scenario, would BOTH messages be executed, or in which scenario, would "exception: integer can't be divider by zero" be executed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting, but there is only one exception being thrown here, and it is being caught in the one place. The only exception related output to stdout you will see is the message in the catch block. Note that you are *not* printing the exception message anywhere. You are essentially "eating" the exception.

Comment: enter two integers
25 0
exception: integer can't be divided by 0
execution contintues....

Comment: What are you looking for?????

Comment: @Jawad - Paul Boddington just answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `"divisor cannot be zero"` is not displayed just because the exception is thrown.

You would only see this message if the exception was *not* caught. You would see it in the stack trace (error message).

If you get rid of the try-catch block and try it then, this is what you should see:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: divisor cannot be zero
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also get rid of the following code:

```
    catch (ArithmeticException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("exception: integer can't be divided by 0");
    }
```

as it is already expressed in the method and would be redundant. Doesn't affect the code. Just letting you know in case you want to clean up the code.

-Manny